# Azure function V2 isn't scaling to handle queue messages quickly

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

This is a Consumption Plan app.  I have 6000+ queue messages in my queue, but my function app won't scale past 10 and fluctuates between 4 and 8 most of the time.  Processor CPU is stuck between 30 and 60%.  None of the dependencies are maxed out.

I've set everything up and it's running well.  Consumption apps don't appear to have any kind of knobs to control or influence scaling.

General flow of code is to pull csv blob, split into 800 smaller json objects and write them out as individual blobs.  Keys for splitting and logging is handled in Cosmos.

The function app should scale up to some level which presses the limits of one of the dependencies.  As it is my Cosmos account is stuck at under 1000 RUs and blob storage should just be able to handle writes all day.  Nothing is maxed out in the current process.

Comment: This doesn't sound like expected behavior. Could you move this issue to our GitHub so we can better track it and provide the following information in your post: time range, function app name, function name(s), and region? (You can [share your function app name privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) if you prefer.) Thanks!